# Creating animations using a visual layer in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, .net, animation, composition, winui-3

My question is more about the styling of the code that uses the visual layer animations than the animations themselves. The problem is that I use animations everywhere: on pages, in controls, in custom effects. But in my opinion it is not very correct to declare and configure animations directly in these places. I'll give you an example. I have a page MyPage.cs

```
    public partial class MyPage : Page
    {
        public MyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _MyPage.PointerPressed += _MyPage_PointerPressed;
        }

        private void ShowMyElement()
        {
            double duration = 250;
            Vector3 from = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            Vector3 to = new Vector3(10,10,0);

            Vector3KeyFrameAnimation myAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
            myAnimation.Target = "Translation";
            myAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration);
            myAnimation.Direction = AnimationDirection.Normal;
            myAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Count;
            myAnimation.IterationCount = 1;
            myAnimation.StopBehavior = AnimationStopBehavior.SetToFinalValue;

            LinearEasingFunction easing = compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction();

            myAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0, from, easing);
            myAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1, to, easing);

            _MyElement.StartAnimation(myAnimation);
        }
        private void HideMyElement()
        {
            double duration = 250;
            Vector3 from = new Vector3(10,10,0);
            Vector3 to = new Vector3(0,0,0);

            Vector3KeyFrameAnimation myAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();
            myAnimation.Target = "Translation";
            myAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration);
            myAnimation.Direction = AnimationDirection.Normal;
            myAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Count;
            myAnimation.IterationCount = 1;
            myAnimation.StopBehavior = AnimationStopBehavior.SetToFinalValue;

            LinearEasingFunction easing = compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction();

            myAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0, from, easing);
            myAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1, to, easing);

            _MyElement.StartAnimation(myAnimation);
        }

        private void _NyPage_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs args)
        {
            PointerPointProperties properties = args.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Properties;

            if (properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
            {
                ShowMyElement()
            }
            if (properties.IsRightButtonPressed)
            {
                HideMyElement()
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, two methods are defined here for showing and hiding an element using smooth animation. But defining animations right here is too redundant and makes the code difficult to read. The problem is that there are many such places in the code, and animations can be much more complex. With a large number of keyframes, counting, forever with different numbers of iterations, with different easing functions, and so on. And my question is what are some good practices for defining such animations. Where can we create and customize such animations to make the code more beautiful and readable and get rid of this overload.

Comment: Put them in a helper function or make custom animations derive from these animations.